# Magento 2.3 pwa studio issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

I followed the official documentation from this url 
https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

But when I run `npm run build` I get the following error

```
lerna ERR! npm run build -s exited 1 in '@magento/venia-concept'
```

Comment: It would be great if you can post the whole command line errors.

Comment: @ramesh please check my ans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If error like this : **lerna ERR! npm run build -s exited 1 in '@magento/venia-concept'**, then run following commands

```
 sudo npm restart
 sudo npm run stage:venia
 sudo npm cache clean -f
 sudo npm install -g n
 sudo n stable / sudo n latest (depends on version)

 sudo npm i @magento/pwa-buildpack
 sudo npm i @magento/upward-js
 sudo npm i @magento/venia-concept
```

then after run **sudo npm run build** command

Comment: Thanks a lot,  it works now but I can't use other backends url, only can use the default backend URL

Comment: I'm working on same thing, I will let you know when I got solution.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will be waiting for your solution

Answer (score 1):

Since **PWA** studio is not released yet, I would recommend to join the slack channel to be up to date on current development and / or issues.

You find the link to join in the documentation at [magento.github.io/pwa-studio](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/)